# How to get make a button when swipe to right to increment a variable

Tags: android

I have list of buttons, I want it that when swiped to right to increment a variable x, and when swipe to left to increment another variable y. 
am storing  the increment in a database which can be retrieve later.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please look at this library https://github.com/amostyaev/SwipeActions. It provides swipe actions for left and right.

Answer (score 0):

To detect at least something you will need some onTouchListener. I didn't really understand what do you want, but I think you can fit with it(it can help you to move button, measure user touches and so on).